# WPF integrate Windows live authentication for Microsoft health vault

Tags: wpf, authentication, live, healthvault

I'm just wondering if there's any way for WPF application integrated with windows live ID?
and it's actually for windows health vault [www.healthvault.com]

so health vault is using windows live id or open id to login into their system.
and what i gonna do is, creating wpf application (instead of web application) for health vault, so all of the login form username pass and everything is handled inside the wpf application without showing/using any internet browser.

so since this's quite new for me, i hope if there's somebody ever did this before especially for health vault system that run on standalone wpf app.

alright, so that's it,
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "offline" authentication, instead of "online" authentication.

Online authentication requires the user to login every time through a web browser.  This is good for web applications, but not good for applications like your's.

Offline authentication lets your application access the user's HealthVault record any time it wants to.  The user never has to login.  To use this, the user must go through a one time connection process.  This is done using a **connect-request**.  After the user goes through this process, your application is given two authentication tokens: a **person-id** and a **record-id**.  These are what your application uses to connect to the user's HealthVault record, so they should be saved to a database or somewhere similar.

This MSDN page should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthvault/cc507205.aspx

Comment: So is it possible to log in without web interface or not? As far as I understood - only difference is, that in offline authentication You log in only once,  but in both cases use web interface?